# How to search for key words AND phrases in my dictionary to execute a function

Tags: python, dictionary

For a little learning by doing project I'm trying to build a simple AI that responds to keywords (e.g."date") and phrases (e.g. "weather tomorrow" with the appropriate function. Its working great for simple keywords but cannot seem to find a phrase.

I already tried to .strip the command but it then it doesnt find anything.

```
from basics_jarvis import *
jarvis_functions = {
    "date": lambda: todays_date(), #These are functions from a different .py
    "datum": lambda: todays_date(),
    "weather": lambda: weather_today(),
    "weather tomorrow": lambda: weather_tomorrow(),
    "tomorrows weather": lambda: weather_tomorrow(),
    "What do you think?": lambda: print("Im not an AI, I dont think")
}
Loop = True
while Loop:
    command = input("Awaiting orders \n")
    for keyword in command.split():     #.strip just breaks the code
        if keyword in jarvis_functions:
            print(jarvis_functions[keyword]())
```

I'm trying to make the program register a key phrase (e.g. "tomorrows weather") in a complete sentence (e.g. "hey, whats tomorrows weather like?" and also if possible compare the keywords and phrases and give the phrases priority since a fitting phrase is more accurate than just one keyword.

This is the first time I'm posting here so I apologies for any mistakes I made! I open to any kind of critique! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simply check if the keyword string is part of the larger string using `if keyword in command:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will calculate the best matching key:

```
def get_best_key(jarvis_fct, words):
    priority = 0
    best_string = ""
    if len(words) == 0:
        return "", 0

    for i in range(0, len(words)+1):
        phrase = " ".join(str(x) for x in words[0:i])
        new_priority = len(words[0:i])
        if phrase in jarvis_fct and new_priority > priority:
            priority = new_priority
            best_string = phrase

    new_words = words[1:len(words)]
    phrase, new_priority = get_best_key(jarvis_fct, new_words)
    if new_priority > priority:
        priority = new_priority
        best_string = phrase

    return best_string, priority

while True:
    command = input("Awaiting orders \n")

    key = get_best_key(jarvis_functions, command.split()))[0]
```

Comment: Wow you solved my problem and then some! Thanks for the great advice!

Answer (score 0):

I added a few print statements to your current code to ilustrate the issue:

```
while True:
    command = input("\nAwaiting orders: ")
    print('received command:', repr(command))

    for keyword in command.split():
        print('   keyword', repr(keyword))
        if keyword in jarvis_functions:
            print(jarvis_functions[keyword]())
```

The result output is:

```
Awaiting orders: hey, whats tomorrows weather
received command: 'hey, whats tomorrows weather'
   keyword 'hey,'
   keyword 'whats'
   keyword 'tomorrows'
   keyword 'weather'

Awaiting orders:
```

As you can see, the command gets taken apart and `tomorrows` and `weather` are no longer together.

---

Instead, I suggest iterating over the keywords and see if they appear in the command. Maybe like this:

```
jarvis_functions = {
    "tomorrows weather": lambda: print('1'),
    "What do you think?": lambda: print("Im not an AI, I dont think"),
}

while True:
    command = input("\nAwaiting orders: ")
    print('received command:', repr(command))

    for keyword, func in jarvis_functions.items():
        print('   keyword', repr(keyword))

        if keyword in command:
            print('   keyword was found')
            func()

            # no need to check other keywords
            break
```

The output would be:

```
Awaiting orders: hey, whats tomorrows weather
received command: 'hey, whats tomorrows weather'
   keyword 'tomorrows weather'
   keyword was found
1

Awaiting orders: something new
received command: 'something new'
   keyword 'tomorrows weather'
   keyword 'What do you think?'

Awaiting orders:
```

I hope that puts you on the right track to a solution.

Comment: As for your question about ranking matches: you could use a `list` instead of a `dict` where the high priority items (phrases) appear before the single keywords. Then you could iterate the list (something like `for elem in jarvis_function_list:`) and exit the loop as soon as a match is found.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have learned a lot from this and will be sure to apply it in the future!